# Find link in a string by regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, windows-8, windows-8.1

So i have a String like so

```
 String org = "Go to http://Apple.com, to see the new Ipad";
```

How do i  return a list of all the words in the String including the url?
For example. The above string should return this list

```
List<String> chopped = new List<String>(){"Go", "to", "http://Apple.com",  " to", "see" , " the", "  new", " Ipad"};
```

I am doing this because i want to reconstruct the string but use the link for something else.

Answer (score 3):

Use `string.Split` method:

```
string[] chopped = org.Split(' ');
```

It returns array of `string` instead of `List<string>`.

But you'll still have to take care of characters like `,`. You can try doing following:

```
string []chopped = org.Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

It will split using both a space and a comma and return results ignoring empty ones.